# 8 nested loop possible combination

Tags: python, equation, brute-force

I've build a program that find 8 different constants in this equation:

```
a*40  +b*0  +c*3  +d*10 +e*10 +f*0  +g*9   +h*7.5 =292(+-5)
a*4   +b*7  +c*5  +d*3  +e*0  +f*0  +g*7   +h*0   =63(+-5)
a*0   +b*6  +c*3  +d*0  +e*0  +f*5  +g*7   +h*0   =85(+-5)
a*175 +b*50 +c*50 +d*75 +e*75 +f*50 +g*110 +h*50  =635(+-5)
```

using brute force (a-h <=5).
but it's take really long time (i know, i know you don't need to say ) 
how can i speed up this process?

basically, this is my code. in reality my program have 4 of them:

```
chofound=[]
konstanta=[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
##    konstanta=[10,0,5,8,2,0,4,
for h in range(0,5):
    for g in range(0,5):
        for f in range(0,5):
            for e in range(0,5):
                for d in range(0,5):
                    for c in range(0,5):
                        for b in range(0,5):
                            for a in range(0,5):
                                hasil= a*konstanta[0]+\
                                       b*konstanta[1]+\
                                       c*konstanta[2]+\
                                       d*konstanta[3]+\
                                       e*konstanta[4]+\
                                       f*konstanta[5]+\
                                       g*konstanta[6]+\
                                       h*konstanta[7]

                                if (hasil>=(292-5) and hasil <=(292+5)):

                                    asd=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
                                    print ("found with config: {}".format(asd))
                                    chofound.append(asd)


return chofound
```

is there any efficient way to actually know the a-h without bruteforce? or any algorithm to make my code run efficiently?

Comment: I have no real idea what you are trying to do but would guess that `itertools` is the key to doing it less verbosely. Also 5**8 iterations is  trivial for a modern computer. Whatever you are doing, the looping itself isn't the bottle neck. Perhaps it is all that printing.

Comment: Using the `array` class from `numpy` would allow you to rewrite this as a vector operation and should be much faster than the for loops.

Comment: Does 292(+-5) mean your solution has a tolerance of +/- 5?

Comment: I'm just curious. Could you use mixed integer solver with fake (or not fake) objective function to enumerate configurations? It should be much more efficient than brute-force. You can use different cut-offs and encode already known solutions as constraints to enumerate everything.

Comment: @waterboy5281 yes it is, the equations has a tolerance of +5 or -5

Comment: are the variables a->h constrained to [0,5]?

Comment: @waterboy5281 since i can't loop it 50 times without stress my cpu too much, yes, i limit those to [0,5]. but i'm looking to do it with 50 loops without breaking my ram limit (8GB)

Comment: In the case of your first equation, you have 6 unknowns and 1 equation to solve. This is undetermined by quite a ways and as such, there are an infinite number of solutions. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @waterboy5281 shortly, i'm trying to get a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h match with 4 of those equation, so when i put [a to h] into first equation, the result must be 292 (+-5), and when i put the same [a to h] to second equation, the result must be 63 (+-5) and so on

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but you might want to look up linear programming and the simplex algorithm to solve this efficiently. You'll find topics talking about finding an "optimal solution", but given you're looking for any solution then some sort of optimal solution will still be useful for you

Comment: In particular, scipy.optimize.linprog is almost certainly the module you're after: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do pretty fast and give you all good config as well:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

konstanta = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])

configs = np.array(list(product(range(5),repeat=8))) # big array: iterating over rows is equivalent to your 8 nested for loops
hasil = (konstanta*configs).sum(axis=1) # element wise multiplication followed by sum over rows
good_configs = configs[(hasil>=0) & (hasil<=10)] # keep only rows where `hasil` is in desired range
```

Comment: this works, however since i can't find any matching solution for all of them. can i change step of the `range(5) ` to 0.1?

Comment: You sure can using `np.arange(0,5,0.1)`.